# Error in civicrm entity leaflet Drupal 9.5

Tags: drupal-views, civicrm-entity, plugin, map

I get this error on my installation with
Drupal 9.5.0, PHP 8.1.12, drupal/leaflet 10.0.5, drupal/civicrm_entity 3.3.0, civicrm/civicrm-core 5.56.1 :

```
`Error : Call to undefined method Drupal\civicrm_entity_leaflet\Plugin\views\style\CivicrmEntityAddressLeafletMap::setResetMapControl() dans Drupal\civicrm_entity_leaflet\Plugin\views\style\CivicrmEntityAddressLeafletMap->buildOptionsForm() (/home/xxx/drupal/web/modules/contrib/civicrm_entity/modules/civicrm_entity_leaflet/src/Plugin/views/style/CivicrmEntityAddressLeafletMap.php ligne 206)`
```

Do you have any solutions to fix this error?
Thanks

Comment: We have one unmerged PR for todo with leaflet, version versions greater than or equal to 2.2.9 https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity/pull/396
Error looks different in what you report, but perhaps will help, or further updates along these lines are necessary. 
Its possible more updates are now required for 10.x of Leaflet.

Comment: yeah, 10.x removed that function that throws the error: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/leaflet/-/blob/10.0.x/modules/leaflet_views/src/Plugin/views/style/LeafletMap.php

What we did is copy/paste/modify that plugin above, and just modify a few things so it works with CiviCRM Address lat/long fields, instead of other Drupal fields.

If you can downgrade to Leaflet 2.2.8 it will work, until we update things. 

I may have to take civicrm_entity_leaflet and make a separate module, and have different versions for the different versions of Leaflet